# May I pass a dask dataframe as input to scikit-learn models?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

Suppose, for example, an instance of sklearn.cluster.KMeans, let's call it "kmeans", and a Dask DataFrame (let's call it "df"). If we do:

```
kmeans.fit(df)
```

Will this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, no.  Most Scikit-learn functions are not Dask aware.

However, the Dask-ML library does have a few estimators that look very similar to the Scikit-Learn estimators that are Dask aware.  You might want to try there.